# MySQL insert statement is executing multiple times and inserting multiple records at a time

Tags: php, mysql, amfphp

I have a newly configured Server.

I am trying simple insert statement in MYSQL.

My code is like below

```
 $stmt=mysqli_prepare($this->db->initCon(),
 "INSERT INTO user_exam_taken
 (user_exam_id, completed, last_question_id, mode, question_ids, time_elapsed, score) 
 VALUES ('".$request->user_exam_id."', '".$request->completed."', 
 '".$request->last_question_id."', '".$request->mode."', '".$request->question_ids."',
 '".$request->time_elapsed."', '".$request->score."');");  
 // This is the entire insert and its not in a loop
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

After executing above insert statement If i look into the table, multiple rows are inserted. But the script is run only once.

I verify i also put a field in that table with type timestamp (`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) which will show the current timestamp value and here this is same for multiple records after that insert statement executed.

**Updated:**

Find below for the entire function

```
function addExamResults(Exam_ResultVO $request)
        {
            $stmt=mysqli_prepare($this->db->initCon(),"INSERT INTO `user_exam_taken` (`user_exam_id`, `completed`, `last_question_id`, `mode`, `question_ids`, `time_elapsed`, `score`) VALUES ('".$request->user_exam_id."', '".$request->completed."', '".$request->last_question_id."', '".$request->mode."', '".$request->question_ids."', '".$request->time_elapsed."', '".$request->score."');");
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $request->id=$this->db->getLastInsertId();
            return $request;
        }
```

i am using amfphp to write service class which has this function and the front-end is Flex app.

As i was saying this entire app was working fine on another server but recently it was moved to **AWS server**.

Comment: Could you also show the code before and after the statement (maybe the whole function?). Is the statement within a loop or something? And please also show the whole SQL statement.

Comment: Please, copy paste the whole mysqli_prepare statement.

Comment: Check also with firebug or chrome dev tools that your browser is only requesting the php script once (empty get urls bugs, empty img src)

Comment: $stmt=mysqli_prepare($this->db->initCon(),"INSERT INTO `user_exam_taken` (`user_exam_id`, `completed`, `last_question_id`, `mode`, `question_ids`, `time_elapsed`, `score`) VALUES ('".$request->user_exam_id."', '".$request->completed."', '".$request->last_question_id."', '".$request->mode."', '".$request->question_ids."', '".$request->time_elapsed."', '".$request->score."');"); // This is the entire insert and its not in a loop, thanks.

Comment: This was working fine on another server, recently moved the app into a new server.

Comment: So the SQL statement seems not to be the problem then. Sounds like your script is being called more than once. Is it called by another function or just a url? What happens before and after the statement? A little more code would be helpful, you can edit your post to add it. I don't think your question can be answered with only the given information... We can only guess now.

Comment: You call this script after a user click on a button or something? In this case, then the user must be click on the button two times (perhaps a fast double click or something). The query seems fine

Answer (score 0):

As the code is above there is no way that multiple rows can be inserted unless:

- The script is called multiple times. You could verify this by using firebug or [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to monitor the requests in your browser.
- There is a trigger that is causing the duplication.

Additionally, refreshing the page multiple times would also cause the multiple inserts.

It would help to have more code in order to see if there is an issue somewhere else.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a trigger cannot insert another row in the same table.

Comment: Depends what the trigger is programmed to do ;) . I've listed all options even if they are a bit unlikely so Op can check.